# exclude specific word and anything that comes after it

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a set of entries, like below:

```
AmirAShabani
Neda
Pouya Na via @gif
Roozbeh
Barsin
Neda via @sticker
```

I want to remove "via" and everything that comes after it. What comes after it has this format: `via @word` where `word` is just alphabets and optional underscores. So the output be like:

```
AmirAShabani
Neda
Pouya Na
Roozbeh
Barsin
Neda
```

I tried [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/S8M5Pc/1):

```
([a-zA-Z ]+)(via @[a-zA-Z_ ])?
```

But the output is:

```
AmirAShabani
Neda
Pouya Na via
Roozbeh
Barsin
Neda via
```

I can sort of understand why this happens, but I can't figure out how to solve it. How can I exclude the word 'via' and anything that comes after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/ via @[a-z_]*/gmi
```

And replace with an empty string.

```js
var str = `AmirAShabani
Neda
Pouya Na via @gif
Roozbeh
Barsin
Neda via @sticker`;
var result = str.replace(/ via @[a-zA-Z_]*/gmi, "");
console.log(result);
```

It looks for exactly what you stated - the word `via`, followed by a space, followed by `@` followed by letters or underscores. I have added a leading space just so it doesn't match `via` that are part of a word.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a regex replace on `\s+via.*$`:

```js
var input = "AmirAShabani\nNeda\nPouya Na via @gif\nRoozbeh\nBarsin\nNeda via @sticker";
var output = input.replace(/\s*via.*$/mg, '');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the programming language as python. You can make the question more specific, by adding the appropriate language tag.

```
>>> li = ['AmirAShabani', 'Pouya Na via @gif' , 'Neda via @sticker', 'Roozbeh', 'Barsin']
>>> for i in range(0, len(li)):
...     li[i] = re.sub(r'\ via\ @\w+', '', li[i])
...
>>> print(li)
['AmirAShabani', 'Pouya Na ', 'Neda ', 'Roozbeh', 'Barsin']
```

Comment: I'm really sorry I didn't mention the language, so that you had to assume. It's `JavaScript`. I've edited the question.

Comment: @AmirAShabani,you can try my pattern in javascript as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
const input = "AmirAShabani\nNeda\nPouya Na via @gif\nRoozbeh\nBarsin\nNeda via @sticker";  
const output = input.split('\n').map(item => {
    const index = item.indexOf("via");
    return index > 0 ? item.substring(0, index - 1): item;
});
console.log(output.join('\n'));
```

Result:

```
AmirAShabani
Neda
Pouya Na
Roozbeh
Barsin
Neda
```